# declare array in bash script errors out: bad array subscript

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I'm trying to debug my script, I'm new at bash and I can't understand the error.
i tried to change it several times and warped line 60 with comments.

the error:

> error: ./scriptdemo.txt: line 60: results_array: bad array subscript

```
#!/bin/bash

echo the script is running

#this part uses preCourses script to get preCourse demends for the input 
course
results_array=''
reqursion_counter=-2
result_courses_counter=0
   ----------------------
   ....some more logic...
   ----------------------
results_array[$result_courses_counter]=${line_of_course[$len-$k-1]}
let result_courses_counter++

   ----------------------
   ....some more logic...
   ----------------------
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `results_array` isn't an array, it's a string: `results_array=''`

Comment: A [mcve] isolating the shortest possible code that causes the same problem would do this question quite a lot of good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is, that you have defined `results_array` as a normal variable, but use it as if it was an array. In bash arrays have separate declaration syntax.

Use this to declare an empty array:

```
results_array=()
```

or

```
declate -a results_array
```

Despite of this, there are quite some other problems with your code, and as @Cyrus suggested, you should have a look at [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) to check your syntax.